# Where to find OpenWeatherMap jar?

Tags: java, openweathermap

I want to create java weather application.

I have code and API from Open Weather but i don't have jar files.

Here is my code

```
public class WeatherTest {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isMetric = true;
        String owmApiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

        /* YOUR OWM API KEY HERE */
        String weatherCity = "Brisbane,AU";
        byte forecastDays = 3;
        OpenWeatherMap.Units units = (isMetric)
            ? OpenWeatherMap.Units.METRIC
            : OpenWeatherMap.Units.IMPERIAL;
        OpenWeatherMap owm = new OpenWeatherMap(units, owmApiKey);
        try {
            DailyForecast forecast = owm.dailyForecastByCityName(weatherCity, forecastDays);
            System.out.println("Weather for: " + forecast.getCityInstance().getCityName());
            int numForecasts = forecast.getForecastCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < numForecasts; i++) {
                DailyForecast.Forecast dayForecast = forecast.getForecastInstance(i);
                DailyForecast.Forecast.Temperature temperature = dayForecast.getTemperatureInstance();
                System.out.println("\t" + dayForecast.getDateTime());
                System.out.println("\tTemperature: " + temperature.getMinimumTemperature()
                    + " to " + temperature.getMaximumTemperature() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the Jar file you are referring to. OpenWeatherMap provides a REST API that you can invoke to get the data

Comment: how? can u help me?

Answer (score 4):

OpenWeatherMap provides a REST API which you can invoke to get the weather data. Please refer https://openweathermap.org/api for the API specification.

In order to invoke it with Java code, you have to implement a REST Java client. There are many ways to do this, but as a start, you can refer https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Alternatively, there are many clients developed wrapping around the OpenWeatherMap API. You can search through them at https://github.com/search?p=1&q=openweathermap&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories

Since you are looking for Java, I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/xSAVIKx/openweathermap-java-api.

An example is available for this library at https://github.com/xSAVIKx/openweathermap-java-api/blob/master/api-examples/src/main/java/org/openweathermap/api/example/DailyForecastExample.java